# Concat Strings in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am generating a Guid in a batch file, then I need to wrap that Guid in curly braces. How do I do that?

```
for /f %%i in ('"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\uuidgen.exe"') do set guid=%%i

ECHO %guid%
pause

set guid = "{"%guid%"}"
ECHO %guid%
```

My solution doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set guid={%guid%}
```

As simple as that. Note that you shouldn't have spaces around the `=` (because your variable name would end in a space and its value would start with one) and quotes are included verbatim in the value unless you quote the complete argument to `set` by using `set "foo=bar"` but that isn't necessary here.

Comment: *facepalm* Don't know how I screwed that up... Thanks!

Comment: You can do it directly in your `for` loop too, by the way: `set guid={%%i}`.